# cannot import name 'keras' from partially initialized modul 'tensorflow'(most likely due to a circular import )

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I simply wrote this code and the error: 
`cannot import name 'keras' from partially initialized modul 'tensorflow'`(most likely due to a circular import) was given. 
I suspect it is because of my python version which is 3.11 but I am not sure since I tried downgrading it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.array([-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([-2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 10.0, 13.0], dtype=float)

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=5000)

print(model.predict([10.0]))
```

Tried downgrading got nothing

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with how you installed tensorflow in your system because the above code runs successfully on a given configuration.

Please check this link to [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) tensorflow in your system as per your system OS.

**Note:** You can only install TensorFlow 2.12 for python version 3.11 as mentioned in this [Tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu). For `TensorFlow<2.12` you need a lesser `python` version to `3.11`.

(Please check this replicated code screenshot)[image]